# How do I change a Google Map to Satellite view after its been drawn

Tags: javascript, wordpress

On the following page, 
http://find-a-mooring.com/berth/a3/
generated by a Wordpress plugin, I want to change the view to Satellite view after the page has loaded. I have tried this:

```
    function setMapSatellite() {
map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE);
    }
setMapSatellite();
```

Where am I going wrong?

Annoyingly the plugin writer (wp-types) have a request to add the feature (change map type) , but have not implemented it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just modify the variable in the global scope like that, because it's not there.  You need to dig into the actual plugin script and modify it. (If you can't convince the author to patch it)

Looks like the script is in the Avada theme's js folder as jquery.fusion_maps.js, line 15 sets the default type, ln 50 applies the settings, ln 80 actually inits the map with the configured options.

Comment: I thought it was possible to change the map type after it has drawn but I must be mistaken

Comment: I can see the map type set in the theme files but this map is built using the plugin so I wonder if that is a bit of a red herring?

Comment: I'm going to download the whole site and see what is setting map type and in what order.

Comment: could I trigger the click event that occurs when the user selects satellite from the map itself?